# Store expression trees in database

Tags: java, database, database-design

I need to store logic conditions in database. for example: `(condition1 || condition2) && condition3` should be stored in database.

I plan to design a table [**ExpressionTree**] to handle the structure:

```
Id
condition
combinationId
nextId(FK->[Condition2Combination.Id])
operator (AND, OR, null)
```

If (condition1 || condition2) && condition3 in the table [ExpressionTree], the records should be:

```
Id  conditionId combinationId nextId  operator
1  condition1   combination1  2       OR
2  condition2   combination1  3       AND
3  condition3   combination1  null    null
```

But the solution is not good, what’s your suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Is your database able to efficiently recursively query these expression trees? If not, I'd go with Stephen C's suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you were actually going to perform database queries over the expression trees, I'd be inclined to store the expressions as a text column ... and parse them on the client side as required.

Comment: +1 For the simple answer. Keep it simple unless you have a serious issue requiring complication.

Comment: +1 This is the (according to me) the only approach for these sort of things. Oh man what I regret storing our expressions as tree's instead on strings. So much trouble.

Comment: @Marcus: do you mean the binary-trees are stored in database?

Comment: @Shengyuan Lu: Yes, we store the entire expression tree (each node-type) objects in the database.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen! It's practical suggestion.

Comment: Another +1 for keeping it simple.  The database isn't evaluating the expressions, so don't complicate persistence with relational nonsense.

Comment: Looks very simple. I have a doubt. If I have to build an expression tree every time I access the database string, will that be a costly operation?

Comment: @LPD - Not really.  A well-written parser is fast.  Probably faster than doing a series of queries to fetch each of the table rows that form the expression tree you are going to use.  (Standard SQL is not good at chaining / performing "closure" queries.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. Am in the exact situation now where I have to build an expression tree from the stored string value(expression in string form as per your suggestion). Any well known algorithms to do that?

Comment: The well known algorithms are called "parsers" :-)

Comment: So for those of us that are going to perform database queries on the expression trees, whats the answer?

Comment: @MartinBrown - Seriously?  Database queries on expression trees?  Why?  I can understand *storing* entire expressions (in serial form) in a database.  I can't understand why you would actually want to do anything other than retrieve them.  But ... I guess ... if you do have use-case that involves actually querying the nodes of the trees, then representing them in the database in parsed form is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the tree structure in your solution.  In particular, I don't think your nextId column is capable of dealing with expressions that have parentheses in them.  But I could be missing something.

I suggest that you look into a way of expressing tree structures that's known as the nested set technique.  In this technique, the "next id" column gets replaced by two columns, called "left id" and "right id" that is capable of expressing which subreets are inside of other subtrees.  This is an over simplified summary of what you're going to find.

Using nested sets, it's easy to come up with a query that reveals the subtree under any given node, or the path from any given node back to the root.

Why is this data in a database?

Comment: Yes, missing something. Left and right children id are needed. The data is business logic configuration.

Comment: Alternatively, I could use parentId instead.